# Joomla RSform $formLayout make tables in a loop or function

Tags: css-tables, joomla4

I have a form that obtains data through sql query and stores it in array. This data is to be displayed in a tabular format in the area "Script called on form display" using $formLayout.

| S.No | data-1 | data-2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | abc1 | xyz1 |
| :---- | :------: | -----: |
| One | abc2 | xyz2 |
| :---- | :------: | -----: |
| One | abc3 | xyz3 |

I have to make multiple tables like above with the same header but different data(available in an array).
Is there any way to do that in a function or loop?